# Jar exists in local Maven repo, but still compile error with "Package does not exist"

Tags: java, maven, compiler-errors, dependencies

`hibernate-validator` is definitely in the `pom.xml` as a dependency:

```
<dependencies>
       ......
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


$ mvn dependency:tree | grep hibernate
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.2.4.Final:runtime
```

And the jar is definitely present in the local filesystem repo:

```
$ find /home/stewart/.m2/repository/ -name "hibernate-validator*"
/home/stewart/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator-parent
/home/stewart/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator-parent/5.2.4.Final/hibernate-validator-parent-5.2.4.Final.pom.sha1
/home/stewart/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator-parent/5.2.4.Final/hibernate-validator-parent-5.2.4.Final.pom
/home/stewart/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator
/home/stewart/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.4.Final/hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.pom.sha1
/home/stewart/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.4.Final/hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.pom
/home/stewart/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.4.Final/hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar
/home/stewart/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.4.Final/hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar.sha1
```

But still this compile failure:

```
$ mvn compile
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Project 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ project ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/stewart/workspace/project/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) @ project ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 15 source files to /home/stewart/workspace/project/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/stewart/workspace/project/src/main/java/project/entity/Entity.java:[3,43] package org.hibernate.validator.constraints does not exist
[ERROR] /home/stewart/workspace/project/src/main/java/project/entity/Entity.java:[15,10] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Email
  location: class project.entity.Entity
[INFO] 2 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have tried both:

```
 mvn -U clean compile
```

And

```
 mvn dependency:purge-local-repository clean compile
```

The `.jar` file is freshly downloaded:

```
$ ll /home/stewart/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.4.Final/hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stewart stewart 704465 Mar  2 11:10 /home/stewart/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.4.Final/hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar
```

And the `.jar` **does** contain the email class:

```
$ unzip -l /home/stewart/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.4.Final/hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar | grep Email.class
 1377  2016-02-17 16:15   org/hibernate/validator/constraints/Email.class
```

**Why can Maven not find the class?**

Comment: And `hibernate-validator` is definitely included as dependency? Could you show `pom.xml` or `mvn dependency:tree`?

Comment: @lexicore  Good call. Added that to top of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `hibernate-validator` has a wrong scope. According to the mvn dependency:tree`the scope is`runtime` and [that means](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html):

> **runtime**
>   This scope indicates that the dependency is not required for compilation, but is for execution. It is in the runtime and test classpaths, but not the compile classpath.

Try changing the scope to compile.

Comment: Yes, just saw it! Doh! Thank you!